# ¿Como se crea este JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json, array

quiero crear un JSON en php con datos de mysql solo que no se como debería de crear la tabla o el código php para que al final el json luzca así, espero su consejo, gracias.

```
[{
"nombre": "Ejemplo",
"url": {
    "small": "imagen1.jpg",
    "medium": "iamgen2.jpg",
    "large": "imagen3.jpg"
},
"fecha": "dd, mm, yy "
},
{
"nombre": "ejemplo",
"url": {
    "small": "imagen4.jpg",
    "medium": "imagen5.jpg",
    "large": "imagen6.jpg"
},
"fecha": "dd, mm, yy"
}]
```

Comment: Hola  @SpaceSpace. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Desde dónde obtendrías los datos para generar el array de objetos? ¿O es siempre la misma salida exacta y sólo te interesa que el php siempre devuelva esos valores literales? No me queda claro el origen. ¿Podrías explicarlo y [edit] la pregunta agregando el código que tengas con esos datos? Mencionás que vienen de la base de datos, ¿cuál es la estructura?

Comment: Hola SpaceSpace, la respuesta seria muy larga, pero básicamente, tendría una tabla para registrar el nombre del, la fecha y un código, y un código, con este código relacionas una tabla que tenga los tamaños de la url. Luego, te apoyas con la funcion json_decode, que el compañero @Maramal ya menciono. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [esta función](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para convertir tu JSON en una array: `json_decode()`

De todas formas el JSON se vería así si fuese un array en PHP:

```
[
    0 => [
        "nombre" => "Ejemplo",
        "url" => [
            "small" => "imagen1.jpg",
            "medium" => "imagen2.jpg",
            "large" => "imagen3.jpg"
        ],
        "fecha" => "dd, mm, yy"
    ],
    1 => [
        "nombre" => "ejemplo",
        "url" => [
            "small" => "imagen4.jpg",
            "medium" => "imagen5.jpg",
            "large" => "imagen6.jpg"
        ],
        "fecha" => "dd, mm, yy"
    ]
]
```